# React Native change state in imported screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to change the `voiceRecordingScreenVisible` value in `AudioRecordingScreen`. How can I do this?

```js
{this.state.voiceRecordingScreenVisible == false ? (
  <View
    style={{
      width: 100 + "%",
      height: 100 + "%",
      position: "absolute",
      zIndex: 20
    }}
  >
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        width: 100 + "%",
        height: 100 + "%",
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
      }}
    />
    <View
      style={{
        width: 85 + "%",
        height: 75 + "%",
        position: "absolute",
        top: 40,
        alignSelf: "center"
      }}
    >
      <AudioRecordingScreen
        screenProps={{
          VoiceChatID: this.state.chatID,
          VoiceSenderID: this.state.userID,
          VoiceTableName: "messages",
          VoiceUserToken: this.state.token
        }}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
) : null}
```

Comment: Do you mean how you can change the `voiceRecordingScreenVisible` value in the state of the component that is rendering `AudioRecordingScreen`? Have you tried `this.setState({ voiceRecordingScreenVisible: true });`?

Comment: I tried this.setState({ voiceRecordingScreenVisible: true }); in AudioRecordingScreen.js but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
// Outside render(), function to set value of voiceRecordingScreenVisible
setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible = (value) => {
  this.setState({voiceRecordingScreenVisible: value})
}

// inside render()
{
  this.state.voiceRecordingScreenVisible == false ? 
    <View style={{width:100+"%",height:100+"%",position:"absolute",zIndex:20}}>
      <TouchableOpacity style{{width:100+"%",height:100+"%",position:"absolute",backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"}}></TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{width:85+"%",height:75+"%",position:"absolute",top:40,alignSelf:"center"}}>
        <AudioRecordingScreen screenProps={{
           VoiceChatID:this.state.chatID,
           VoiceSenderID:this.state.userID,                          
           VoiceTableName:"messages",      
           VoiceUserToken:this.state.token,

           // pass function to set the value voiceRecordingScreenVisible
           setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible: this.setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible   
        }}/>
       </View>                
     </View> : null 

}
```

And call the function 'setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible' `this.props.screenProps.setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible` in AudioRecordingScreen, where you required.

Answer (score 0):

you should use arrow function to solve the keyword this problem, like setVoiceRecordingScreenVisible: (boolean) => this.setState({voiceRecordingScreenVisible: boolean}), here in the scope of the arrow function, this binds to the same value of where the arrow function has been created. and the parameter boolean is the value you pass to the arrow function.